# Neural Network with Input Depending on Variable

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, mathematical-optimization

Let's say we have a fully connected network with 1 hidden layer. Let's call the input to the network `X`. Suppose now that there is a variable `Z` on which the input depends, i.e. `X = f(Z,D)` where `D` is the training data available.  After that, `X` is then fed to the network, e.g. the output will be `Y=f(X,W)`, where W and b are indeed the network weights and biases.

In other words, the input of the network depends both on the training data and on a variable. Now, when writing the loss function in terms of `X`, clearly the optimization will also depend on the value of `Z`, therefore the network will learn that variable too.

Does this make sense? Is this kind of model still a Neural Network in the general sense?

P.S.: `Z` is a trainable variable for the model. The network runs (in tensorflow) and the variable is actually being learnt, my wonder is more on the architecture level/mathematical details of such a model.

Comment: I think, you are not properly defining your equation. `Y = f(X, Z)` where `X` is input and `Z` is network parameters, `X` is defined on the domain `D`. `f` is the network structure; `Y` is the output.

Comment: That's the thing, this is before the data get fed into the normal hidden layers. So, `X = f(Z,D)` is the input that I then use feed to a fully-connected network, e.g. `Y=f(X,W)` where `W` and `b` are indeed the network weights and biases.

Comment: you may include this information in your question, otherwise it's incomplete

Comment: Does variable Z have some finite range?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, not really but f(Z,D) kind of maps it into an expected range.